# Application of Riemann Mapping Theorem to conformal automorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega=G -\{a,b\},$ where $G$ is non-empty simply connected bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and $a \neq b.$ Could anyone advise me how to find all conformal automorphism of $\Omega \ ?$ I tried to invoke the use of Riemann mapping theorem to no avail.

Thank you/

Comment: All the Riemann mapping theorem does, as far as I can see, is reduce this to the case that $G = D^2, a = 0$, with $b>0$ real. This should still not be easy...

Comment: Noted, So what would be your advice?

Comment: (I do not know if the following is true, but it seems likely to be.) Prove that all conformal automorphisms of this $G$ extend to automorphisms of the disc; then it suffices to check which automorphisms of $D^2$ keep these two points fixed or switch them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still figuring out how to prove all conformal automorphisms of $G$ extend to automorphisms of $\mathbb{D} \ .$

Comment: Like I said, I don't have a proof; it may not even be true. But I feel like it probably is.

Comment: By riemann mapping theorem, there exists conformal $g: G \to \mathbb{D},$ let $f$ be any conformal automorphism of $G,$ so $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is conformal automorphism of $\mathbb{D} \ ?$

Comment: I'm assuming $G = \Bbb D$ by the bit in my first comment. I meant to say in my second comment "automorphisms of $\Omega$ extend".

Answer (score 3):

Since $G$ is bounded, every holomorphic map $f:\Omega\to\Omega$ extends to a holomorphic map on $G$. (Singularities are removable when the function is bounded nearby.) The extended map (call it $F$) still takes values in $\Omega$, since its image is open. And it is still injective, because when injectivity of a holomorphic map fails, there is an infinite set of points with multiple preimages. (More precisely: if $w$ has at least two preimages $z_1,z_2$, so does every point sufficiently close to $w$; to prove this, consider the images of  the neighborhoods of $z_1,z_2$.)

So, $F$ is an injective holomorphic map, hence a  homeomorphism onto its image. Since $G$ is simply connected, so is $F(G)$. We conclude that $F(G)=G$. The problem reduces to identifying conformal automorphisms of $G$ that map the set $\{a,b\}$ onto itself.

This is where the Riemann mapping theorem helps by reducing to the case $G=\mathbb D$ and $a=0$. There are two Möbius transformations $\phi$ that satisfy $\phi(\{0,b\})=\{0,b\}$. One is the identity map, the other is an involution exchanging $0$ and $b$.

Comment: how to you know the function doesn't have poles at $a$ and/or $b$?

Comment: "Singularities are removable when the function is bounded nearby."

Comment: I see, the boundedness of the region implies its automorphisms are bounded.